# Context menu does not appear in Bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Why is my menu not displayed when right-clicking on the graph, but there is an output in my browser console: "context menu". I expect a context menu called by right-clicking for a graph node.

I've tried to use default MenuItem, but it's abstract, so browser throws exception.

My bokeh version is 3.1.0
My bokeh server doesn't tell me anything, the bokeh documents are so bad :_(

Here is my code:

```
# bokeh staff
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show
from bokeh.models.graphs import NodesOnly
from bokeh.models.ui.menus import Action
from bokeh.models import (
    GraphRenderer,
    Circle,
    StaticLayoutProvider,
    Menu,

    Dropdown,
    HoverTool,
    ColumnDataSource,
)
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral8
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS

# my staff
from tree import get_tree

tree = get_tree()

edges = []

for i, v in tree.items():
    for k in v["link_to"]:
        edges.append([i, k])

plot = figure(
    width=1080,
    height=720,
    x_range=(0, 1081),
    y_range=(0, 721),
    tools="box_zoom,reset",
)

renderer = GraphRenderer()
renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data = dict(
    index=list(tree.keys()),
    fill_color=Spectral8[0: len(tree.keys())]
)

tree_attrs_keys = list(
    tree[list(tree.keys())[0]]['attrs'].keys()
)

tree_attrs_values = {k: [None] for k in tree_attrs_keys}  # name:[], smth: []

for _, v in tree.items():
    for attr_name, attr in v['attrs'].items():
        tree_attrs_values[attr_name].append(attr)

node_attrs = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        index=[-1] + list(tree.keys()),
        **tree_attrs_values
    )
)

renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(radius=10)
renderer.inspection_policy = NodesOnly()

renderer.edge_renderer.data_source.data = dict(
    start=[i for i, j in edges], end=[j for i, j in edges]
)

graph_layout_provider = StaticLayoutProvider(
    graph_layout={k: v["pos"] for k, v in tree.items()}
)
renderer.layout_provider = graph_layout_provider

# define a data source for selected nodes
hovered_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(index=[-1]))

# define a hover tool that outputs the index of the hovered node
hover_tool = HoverTool(
    callback=CustomJS(
        args={"source": renderer.node_renderer.data_source, 'hovered': hovered_source},
        code="""
        var indices = cb_data.index.indices;
            if (indices.length > 0) {
                var index = indices[0];
                hovered.index = index;
                source.change.emit();
                hovered.change.emit();
            }
        """
    ),
    renderers=[renderer.node_renderer]
)

hover_tool.tooltips = None

plot.renderers.append(renderer)
plot.add_tools(hover_tool)
plot.dot(0, 0)

menu_items = []
idx = node_attrs.data['index'].index(
    hovered_source.data['index'][0]
)
for key in node_attrs.data.keys():
    if key != "index":
        data = node_attrs.data[key][idx]
        menu_items.append(dict(name=f'{key}: {data}'))

menu = Menu(items=[Action(**mi) for mi in menu_items])

plot.context_menu = menu
curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

My tree is something like:

```
1: {
            'link_to': [2, 3, 4],
            'pos': (130, 25),
            'attrs': {
                'name': 'Node 1',
                'notice': ''
            }
        },
        2: {
            'link_to': [3],
            'pos': (150, 100),
            'name': '2',
            'attrs': {
                'name': 'Node 2',
                'notice': ''
            }
        },
        3: {
            'link_to': [],
            'pos': (250, 130),
            'name': '3',
            'attrs': {
                'name': 'Node 3',
                'notice': ''
            }
        },
        4: {
            'link_to': [1],
            'pos': (400, 500),
            'attrs': {
                'name': 'Node 4',
                'notice': ''
            }
        }
    }
```